# Вызов функции из функции и возвращение нескольких значений

Tags: python, функции

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы программа не выводила кортеж, а записывала в каждую переменную своё значение (`a=sum, b='empty'` или `a=sum, b=mult`) при вызове функции из другой функции

```
def function(a, b):
    num1 = a
    num2 = b
    sum = num1 + num2
    mult = num1 * num2
    if b == 100:
        return sum, "empty"
    else:
        return sum, mult

def function2(a, b):
    print(a)
    if str(b) == "empty":
        print("b=empty")
    else:
        print(b)

a = 5
b = 100
function2(function(a, b), 123)
```

Я понимаю, что `function2` принимает два аргумента: `a` в качестве вызова другой функции и `b` в качестве числа 123, поэтому и записывает в `a` кортеж

Comment: `function2(function(a, b)[0], 123)`. Так из результата `function(a, b)` заберётся только первое возвращаемое значение (`sum`), а вторым аргументом будет 123. Кстати: лучше не называть переменные именами встроенных функций (`sum`).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась.

```
def function(a, b):
    num1 = a
    num2 = b
    sum = num1 + num2
    mult = num1 * num2
    if b == 100:
        return sum, "empty"
    else:
        return sum, mult

def function2(a):
    print(a[0])
    if str(b[1]) == "empty":
        print("b=empty")
    else:
        print(b[1])

a = 5
b = 100
function2(function(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
...
def function2(a, b):
    print(a)
    a, b = a               # +++
    if str(b) == "empty":
        print("b=empty")
    else:
        print(b)
...
```